# UiAutomatorTestCase getUiDevice() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, adt

I am getting null when calling getUiDevice() in an UiAutomatorTestCase.

```
public class DemoTestCase extends UiAutomatorTestCase{
    public void testDemo() {
        assertTrue(getUiDevice().pressHome());
        Bundle status = new Bundle();
        status.putString("msg", "This is a demo test and I just pressed HOME");
        status.putString("product", getUiDevice().getProductName());
        Point p = getUiDevice().getDisplaySizeDp();
        status.putInt("dp-width", p.x);
        status.putInt("dp-height", p.y);
        getAutomationSupport().sendStatus(Activity.RESULT_OK, status);
    }
}
```

I have tried with different examples and always getting null, I don't get the UI device. This test is called from the main Java class of the app.

I use an android VirtualBox when running the uiautomator test. I send the app by using adb push and run it with adb shell uiautomator runtest `my.jar -c my.main.Class`

If I don't use `getUiDevice()` everything runs ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `getUiDevice()` from another class you have to declare your variable in your constructor and call it from the original class.

```
public class OriginalClass extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
    public void runTestInAnotherClass() {
        DemoTestCase demoTestCase = new DemoTestCase(getUiDevice());
        testDemo();
    }

}

public class DemoTestCase extends UiAutomatorTestCase{
    UiDevice uiDevice;

    public DemoTestCase(UiDevice device) {
        uiDevice = device;
    }

    public void testDemo() {
        assertTrue(device.pressHome());
        Bundle status = new Bundle();
        status.putString("msg", "This is a demo test and I just pressed HOME");
        status.putString("product", device.getProductName());
        Point p = device.getDisplaySizeDp();
        status.putInt("dp-width", p.x);
        status.putInt("dp-height", p.y);
        getAutomationSupport().sendStatus(Activity.RESULT_OK, status);
    }
}
```